transmit data from py file to plc with rs232 protocol
Description of the Problem: I am using a PLC FX3U and have programmed it with the lệnh MOV D1 D10 và LD D10 K1. When I set the value of D1 to 1234, the Y00 indicator light should turn on. However, the light does not turn on.
What I’ve Tried:
I verified that the PLC is correctly configured with the baud rate of 38400 and other serial settings.
I tested sending commands to the PLC using Python and the serial library, but the responses indicate errors.
I confirmed that setting D1 to 1234 makes Y00 turn on when manually tested on the PLC.
Question: Why does the Y00 light not turn on even though the value of D1 is correctly set and the commands appear to be correct? Are there any additional steps or checks I should perform?
